# NSInvalidArgumentException, reason unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

When processing a json response I a get the below error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DADGList setDescription:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae88880'

The class it crashed on:

```
@implementation DADGList

-(id)copy
{
    DADGList *list = [[DADGList alloc] init];
    list.identifier = self.identifier;
    list.name = [self.name copy];
    list.description = [self.description copy];
    list.created = [self.created copy];
    list.itemCount = self.itemCount;
    list.shareLink = [self.shareLink copy];

    return list;
}

+(DADGList *)listFromDictonary:(NSDictionary *)dictonary
{
    DADGList *list = [[DADGList alloc] init];
    NSLog( @"%@", dictonary );
    list.identifier = [[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_id"] integerValue];
    list.itemCount = [[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_items_count"] integerValue];
    list.name = [NSString stringWithString:[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_name"]];
    list.description = [NSString stringWithString:[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_description"]];
    list.created = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_created"] doubleValue]];
    list.shareLink = [NSString stringWithString:[dictonary objectForKey:@"list_share_url"]];

    return list;
}
```

and the dictonary that is past to listFromDictonary:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename your `description` property for something else as this is a field already existing in the iOS echosystem (NSObject if I am not mistaken) and that creates all sort of weird crash like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `core data` maybe you need to implement the following instance:

```
Mall(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Mall", in: context)!, insertInto: nil)
```

Where `Mall` is my entity and `context` is my view context.